# Identifying elements in Iframe after content change using Selenium

Tags: c#, iframe, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**The Problem**

I have an iframe which Contains a form , once I submit the form the content of the iframe changes to something else based on the information . So I need to verify the elements/texts in result as a part of my test

**What I did**

I used Switch().Frame to submit the data to iframe , and used " WebDriverWait "  to wait for results (I am waiting for an element )

**The issue**

After submission new elements do not get recognized and "wait for element" fails after time out even though the result screen visually loaded to the iframe ( I also tried increasing the time out , but no luck )

---

Am i doing something wrong ? or Can anyone give me suggestion ?

highly appreciate any help

Comment: Is the content loading within the iframe after submitting the form? If so You need to swtich to that iframe again to verify the content inside it.

Comment: Verify the driver.PageSource and try to identify in which frame/window you are after the form is submitted. That way you can see why the wait is timing out.

Comment: Thanks for the comments , I tried Himansu's answer below and it worked
(switching back to default , wait and switch to frame again )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working on the same scenario and this is working for it, you can try :

```
     driver.switchTo().frame(frameid);
       driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name=\"login\"]")).click();//whatever you want to perform in frame.
      driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
       Thread.sleep(3000);
      driver.switchTo().frame(frameid);
      driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name=\"login\"]")).getText();//Whar ever you want to perform.
```

If you have any concern so let me know.
Enjoy!

Comment: Pleasure of mine Enjoy Dear :)

Answer (score 0):

I think after submission - the element get changed now the element do not lie in iframe.

Use:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

And try recognizing element.

I am not pretty much sure. but can you give it a try.

Comment: can you provide me application access if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Is the complete form loading again or just some text/info that you are providing?

Comment: Thanks for the comment , actually entire content changed and Himashu's method worked